How exactly do I find the values of A, B, C, and D?
The question states "Consider the LRC-series circuit with $L=0.5$H, $R=20\Omega$, $C=0.001$F, and $E(t) = 400\sin(60t) + 500\cos(40t)$. Find the complementary function and the particular solution.
To find the complementary function, I set up the equation as $1/2q'' + 20q'+1/0.001q=0$ and found it to be: $q=e^{-20t}(c_1\cos(40t)+ c_2\sin(40t)$
For the particular solution, the guess has the form of $q_p(t)=A\sin(60t)+B\cos(60t)+C\sin(40t)+D\cos(40t)$
I have found the first and second derivative of the guessed form of the particular solution and plugged it into the original equation ( $1/2q''+20q'+1000q'=400\sin(60t)+500\cos(40t)$ ), but I am stuck in how to set up the equations to find the value of $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$. Any detailed help on how to proceed past this step will be appreciated This is what I have done so far

It would be better to include a summary of what you have done so far in the question, not in a link. You don't need to rigourously show each step of the maths, just explain what you started with, what you did and where you've got to

Hint: your final equation has some coefficient times $\sin(60t)$ on both the left and right. For both sides to be equal for all $t$, what must the relationship between those two coefficients be?
Don't forget on the LHS you have an implied coefficient of $0$ for both $\sin(40t)$ and $\cos(60t)$

I was overcomplicating the simplification process. It makes more sense looking at the equations now. I guess most of the work is done through inspection. thank you
